# excel refresh microsoft query and graphs at the same time

Tags: excel, pivot-table, microsoft-query

I am running Excel 2016, using Microsoft query connecting to sql server retrieving some data into a pivot table and creating a graph, this works fine.

I have a cell that I can change the date I am interested in, the underlying data then changes, but I have to right click on a graph and say refresh.

Is it possible to have the graph refresh when the data does?  I have seen examples of charts changing when the data is in excel, but can't seem to find anything when pulling from an external data source.
thanks

Comment: Typically charts and graphs in excel update automatically when their source data changes... what version of Excel are you using? Maybe you need a `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: Hi Excel 2016, I was a little surprised it didn't change automatically

Comment: Does the data get added directly to the data model? Or do you return it to the grid first, and then make a PivotTable out of it?

Comment: It gets returned to the grid then I make a PivotTable